# Finding functions that fulfil a condition and are strictly increasing.

Tags: sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes, sequence-of-function

I need to find $\lambda_{n}(t)$ such that it gives $0$ for $t = 0$ and $p + \dfrac{1}{n}$ for $t = p$ and $1$ for $t = 1$.
The first case is fulfilled but I can't seem to find a function that would give me this for the second case. Thanks so much

$$\lambda_{n}(t) = \begin{cases}
(1+\dfrac{1}{nt})t, & t \in [0, p)\\
(1-\dfrac{1}{nt})t + \dfrac{2}{n}, & t \in [p,1]
\end{cases}
$$
It also needs to be stricly increasing.

Comment: You mean $\lambda_n(p)$

Comment: Yes sorry, edited

Comment: It would be wise not to use one letter in two meanings, as in $p \in [0, p)$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin True, i'll edit it now.

Comment: Now your example looks like an exceedingly convoluted way to write $t+{1\over n}$, which fails the conditions at 0 and at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your second function can only be increasing if $p + \frac{1}{n} \leq 1$

You can always use the straight line function between $(p, p+\frac{1}{n}) \rightarrow (1,1)$

$$\frac{\lambda_n-1}{p+\frac{1}{n} - 1} = \frac{t-1}{p - 1} $$
$$\lambda_n(t) = \frac{1-(p+\frac{1}{n})}{1-p}(t-1) + 1$$